# Can you use LINQ extension method operators in an ASP.NET databinding expression?

Tags: asp.net, linq, data-binding

Is it possible to use a LINQ extension method within an ASP.NET databinding expression?

Within a GridView that is bound to a Customer collection which in-turn has a related Phones collection the following Eval expression fails:

```
<%# Eval("Phones.Single(p => p.PhoneTypeId == 2)") %>
```

The error message I receive is: 'First(p => p' is not a valid indexed expression

Is this possible to use the LINQ extension method operations within a binding expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not.  Lambda expressions are an advanced expression type that is not supported by Asp.Net data binding expressions.  Binding expressions are a much simpler language.  They only support property and field names (including indexer expressions).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx